using html2Pdf library printing table header on every page
I’m using the html2pdf library to generate a PDF from an HTML table. The table spans multiple pages, but the header only appears on the first page. How can I make sure the table header is repeated on every page of the PDF?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
    function saveAsPdf() {
        var selMonth = $('#monthsListView').val();
        var selYear = $('#yearsListView').val();

        setTimeout(function () {
            // Use html2pdf to convert HTML content to PDF
            html2pdf(combinedTableDiv, {
                margin: 10,
                filename: 'OutsiderAttendance' + selMonth +'/' +selYear + '.pdf', // Corrected filename
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'landscape' },
                 pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] }
                

            }).then(function (pdf) {
                // Save the PDF or do other actions
                pdf.save();
            });
        }, 1000); 
    }  this is my function that prints and download  pdf what should i change in this ?

